# blender 4.0, how to use python set render denoiseer = Optix

Tags: python

blender use python set like this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2igV.png

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIF](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Comment: did u try bpy.context.scene.cycles.denoiser = 'OPTIX'?